# React Native SQLite gives "None of these files exists "node_modules\react-native-sqlite-storage\lib\sqlite.core.js"

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite

Hi I have an error in App.tsx while I declare and using SQLite.

I have imported rigth and I am going on tutoriols but it gives

"node_modules\react-native-sqlite-storage\lib\sqlite.core.js" error.

I have react native version 0.69.1

here the declaretion and using in App.tsx

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

const db=SQLite.openDatabase({
  location:"default",
  name:"SQLitedb",
},()=>{console.log('basarili')},(err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

tried this already?

patch [a link](https://github.com/mitsuharu/Ubepedia/blob/20220625/app/patches/react-native-sqlite-storage%2B6.0.1.patch)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32440986)